# What does spectrum of sin(t) looks like in real life?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

In real life, negative frequency doesn't exist.
[image]

But `x(t) = sin(t)` has 2 spikes at -1 and 1 in X(w), corresponding to `f = +- 1/2pi`.

So what does the spectrum of sin(t) looks like in real life? Does it only have 1 big spike at f = 1/2pi? If so, how can it be distinguished from cos(t)?

Thank you.
Edit: by real life, I mean what is the output when you measure the signal with a frequency analyzer (that must exist, right?)

Comment: sin(t) is real so it exist, and the right hand side equals a real number so it exists. But how do you measure -1Hz in real life ?

Comment: How can you start with "in real life, ..." but then end with "that must exist, right?" If you want to ask about a physical quantity, you have to tell us *what* that quantity is. I don't think your question is possible to answer without more details on what "real life" constitutes - especially when you deal with something like the Fourier transform which isn't really directly measurable in the first place.

Comment: The function $x\to \sin x$ has (minimal) period $2\pi$ (or, equivalently, $-2\pi$). Questions about what a physical box does with different signals (or philosophical questions about which one is more real) aren't really a good fit here.

Comment: Also you can see this negative frequency effect if you look at an AM modulated signal. In a spectrum analysiser you will see the upper side bands from the signals positive frequencies and the lower sidbands from the negative frequencies.

Comment: Now the frequency analyzer are digital, they sample the signal, if periodic they detect the period, and they compute its discrete Fourier transform. If you hate complex numbers then $A(\omega),A(-\omega)$ encode the phase and amplitude of the sine component with period $\omega$. To define the phase we need to choose or $t_0$, otherwise we can talk of the change in phase wrt frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that there is a spinning disk with an object sitting on it. And you are looking at the object side on.  You will see the object moving back and forth in a classic sine wave.

Now from just the displacement of the object can you tell if the disk is moving clockwise or counterclockwise?

The negative frequency value corresponds to the clockwise spinning disk. However since $sin(x) = -sin(-x)$ a clockwise spinning disk and a counter clockwise spinning disk with the object placed on the opposite side of the disk look identical.

So the Fourier transform reflects both of these solutions.